# Skipping if condition in result set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a Login function in java to test if a user exists in a database. If it does, than in prints out the status (1 , 2) with 1 being admin and 2 a student.
In the result set, I have if conditions to test out the values.
My problem is that the if statement for status == 1 is skipped.
Here's my code:

```
public void Login(String username,String password) {

        try{
       Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       String query = "Select iduser, username, pass, status, firstname, lastname from users";
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);   
            if (rs.next()) {

                int iduser = rs.getInt("iduser");
                String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
                String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
                int status = rs.getInt("status");

                if(status == 1){
                    System.out.println("Admin");
                }
                else if(status == 2){
                    System.out.println("Student");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User not found!");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Here is the table in my database
[image: Database User Table]

Comment: maybe the status is 0 or another number not 1 or 2, can you print it to check what is the status return ?

Comment: This means `int status = rs.getInt("status");` don't return 1 in any condition. You need to look why `getInt` don't return 1.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot for the users

Comment: It is easier to learn how to debug than all the typing and time you are using on SO. A simple breakpoint will let you evaluate what the value of status is

Comment: You have a typo, you don't close the catch correctly

Comment: @qwerty12345, kindly have a look at my solution and let me know if it helps. Maybe you can debug and check your code.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but consider [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for storing passwords

Comment: @Andreas, it's just part of homework, I'll encrypt the passwords later on

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `if (rs.next())` with `while(rs.next())`.

`String query = "Select iduser, username, pass, status, firstname, lastname from users";`
Fetches 'multiple' required records from your table.

The record with `iduser` 2 might be placed in the table and/or retrieved before `iduser` 1.

Comment: it printed both Student and Admin

Comment: I fixed it, changed a bit.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

So I've changed a bit in my code and database structure. I added a jComboBox to select status, and changed the Login function.
On the button login I added the jComboBox as a second condition and it worked. 
The Login function is now this:

```
public boolean Login(String username, String password, String status) {
   try{
       PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from users where username=? and pass=? and status = ?");
       pst.setString(1, username);
       pst.setString(2, password);
       pst.setString(3, status);
       ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
       if(rs.next()){            
           return true;    
       } else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Does Not Exist");
           return false;
       }         
   } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to close `pst` in case of exception - otherwise you have a resource leak